# Bash script. Is there way to shorten my code?

Tags: bash, shell

This is a code for calculator which give you results in words. I use many if conditions. I plan to do it with the numbers up to 30. Is there way to shorten it?

```
#! bin/bash

    while true; do

    read -p "First number: " n1
        read -p "Second number: " n2
        PS3="what's the operation? "
        select ans in add subtract multiply divide; do
            case $ans in
                add) op='+' ; break ;;
                subtract) op='-' ; break ;;
                multiply) op='*' ; break ;;
                divide) op='/' ; break ;;
                *) echo "invalid response" ;;
            esac
        done
        ans=$(echo "$n1 $op $n2" | bc -l)
        if [ $ans == 1 ] ; then
         printf "%s %s %s = one \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2"
        elif [ $ans == 2 ] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = two \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 3 ] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = three \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 4 ] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = four \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 5 ] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = five \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 6 ] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = six \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 7] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = seven \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 8] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = eight \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 9] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = nine \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
     elif [ $ans == 10] ; then 
       printf "%s %s %s = ten \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2";
        fi
```

Comment: Use an array: `nums=(zero one two three four...)`

Comment: there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ dedicated to review working code. Maybe you should post there your code to get a lot of feedback.

Comment: Side note: your shebang line is missing a forwards slash, should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: As another aside, `==` is a bashism; the standard-compliant `test` operator for string comparison is just `=`. And you're missing some quotes.

Comment: Use `case ${ans} in` (or better the array)

Comment: Yup. `printf '%s %s %s = %s\n\n' "$n1" "$op" "$n2" "${nums[$ans]}"`

Comment: ...btw, the expansion should be quoted in `[ "$ans" = 1 ]`

Comment: but anyhow, I do agree that this kind of general "how can this be improved?" is too broad to be a good question on StackOverflow; note the guidance in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic that a SO question needs to be specific and answerable ("answerable" meaning not just that people can add something helpful to a discussion, but that a complete, canonical and correct answer is possible -- criteria effectively incompatible with open-ended questions).

Comment: See [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for guidance on which questions are appropriate either here or on our sister site [codereview.se] (and which are appropriate on neither).

Comment: (now, if you changed this into, say, "how can I tersely map numbers to strings in bash?" and removed everything unrelated to that narrow, specific question, **that** could be a good StackOverflow question).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Code Review StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

  read -p "First number: " n1
  read -p "Second number: " n2
  PS3="what's the operation? "
  select ans in add subtract multiply divide; do
      case $ans in
          add) op='+' ; break ;;
          subtract) op='-' ; break ;;
          multiply) op='*' ; break ;;
          divide) op='/' ; break ;;
          *) echo "invalid response" ;;
      esac
  done
  ans=$(echo "$n1 $op $n2" | bc -l)
  res=(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven)
  printf "%s %s %s = ${res[ans]} \n\n" "$n1" "$op" "$n2"
done
```

Since the original code shows no error checking, I left it out, too (as an excercise, as usual).